# installing pulseaudio 5 has crashed system settings and other icons

Tags: unity, sound, pulseaudio, system-settings

I installed Pulseaudio 5 as I need to send sound to satellite Android speakers.
Any way after install: Pulse audio does not boot, System settings won't boot(from icon or the menu), sound icon missing in fact even keyboard command to launch terminal doesn't even work I have to use launcher icon to launch terminal.
I have tried:

> sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center 
>   sudo apt-get install unity-control-center

and

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

and

> sudo apt-get install unity-control-center-signon gnome-control-center-unity

I tried un installing Pulseaudio 
I tried uninstalling unity system settings in App manager and then reinstalling again

restarting each time after all of these attempts but nothing has sorted the problem I need help!

Comment: I get this result when attempting to start system settings in terminal :<br>Alienware-Ubuntu:~$ unity-control-center
libpulsecommon-4.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-control-center-1/panels/libsound.so
libGL error: Couldn't dlopen libudev.so.1 or libudev.so.0, driver detection may be broken.
unity-control-center: ../../../../src/loader/loader.c:129: asserted_dlsym: Assertion `result' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)